# Stdin with getc producing additional output, and opening file causing segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stdout, stdin, fopen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

#define A 65
#define Z 90
#define a 97
#define z 122
#define NEWLINE 10

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int noArgReverse();
    int argReverse(int i, char* c[]);
    if (argc == 1){
        if (noArgReverse() == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
    if (argc > 1){
        if (argReverse(argc, argv) == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr, "unknown error detected.\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

int noArgReverse()
{
    char charInput[10000];
    int pointerArray[5000];
    int pointerCount = 0;
    bool wordStart = false;
    int indexer;
    int lineLength;
    int parser;
    char currInput;

    pointerArray[0] = 0; // first word would start at 0 be default

    while (currInput != EOF){
        lineLength = 0;
        indexer = 0;
        pointerCount = 0;
        while ((currInput = getc(stdin)) != NEWLINE){
            /*
             * I am implementing a 10,000 char limit, as this seems an
             * unreasonable length.
             */
            if (lineLength == 9999){
                fprintf(stderr, "Line length exceeded 10,000 chars. "
                        "This line and, if in the middle of a word,"
                        "will be split.\n");
                break;
            }

            if (!wordStart){
                if ((currInput >= A && currInput <= Z) || (currInput >= a && currInput <= z)){
                    wordStart = true;
                }
            }

            while (wordStart){
                charInput[lineLength++] = currInput;
                currInput = getc(stdin);
                //if the word has ended
                if ((currInput < A || currInput > Z) && (currInput < a || currInput > z)){
                    wordStart = false;
                    charInput[lineLength++] = '\0';
                    if (pointerCount != 0){ // at least one word has been added
                        ++indexer;
                        pointerArray[indexer] = pointerCount;
                        pointerCount = lineLength;
                    }
                    else //first word of the line to be added
                        pointerCount = lineLength;
                }
            }
        }

        while (indexer >= 0){
            parser = pointerArray[indexer--];
            while (charInput[parser] != '\0')
                fprintf (stdout, "%c", charInput[parser++]);
            fprintf (stdout, " ");
        }
        fprintf (stdout, "\r\n");

        if (lineLength == 0){
            currInput = EOF;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int argReverse (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char charInput[10000];
    int pointerArray[5000];
    int pointerCount = 0;
    bool wordStart = false;
    int indexer;
    int lineLength;
    int parser;
    char currInput;
    FILE *currentFile;

    while (argc > 0){
        currentFile = fopen(argv[argc--], "r");
        while ((currInput = getc(currentFile)) != EOF){
            lineLength = 0;
            indexer = 0;
            pointerCount = 0;
            while (currInput != NEWLINE){
                /*
                 * I am implementing a 10,000 char limit, as this seems an
                 * unreasonable length for a single line.
                 */
                if (lineLength == 9999){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Line length exceeded 10,000 chars. "
                            "This line and, if in the middle of a word, the word, "
                            "will be split.\n");
                    break;
                }

                if (!wordStart){
                    if ((currInput >= A && currInput <= Z) || (currInput >= a && currInput <= z)){
                        wordStart = true;
                    }
                }

                while (wordStart){
                    charInput[lineLength++] = currInput;
                    currInput = getc(currentFile);
                    //if the word has ended
                    if ((currInput < A || currInput > Z) && (currInput < a || currInput > z)){
                        wordStart = false;
                        charInput[lineLength++] = '\0';
                        if (pointerCount != 0){ // at least one word has been added
                            ++indexer;
                            pointerArray[indexer] = pointerCount;
                            pointerCount = lineLength;   
                        }
                        else //first word of the line to be added
                            pointerCount = lineLength;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(currentFile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So for my first function, I'm getting an error I can't seem to get to the bottom to while debugging, or, rather, I'm not sure how to solve.  The function should take input from `stdin`, and print the words in reverse order (the chars should remain in order, so "This is a sentence" should be "sentence a is This").  Simple enough.  However, when I give sample input, the output I get is all wrong.

**input:**

```
This is sample
input for testing
```

**output:**

```
testing for input sample is This

This
```

The input has one return, but the output has an extra return between the lines, and does not split the lines.

So, it's not printing the newline when it should, and it's printing the first inputted word again when it ends.

The second issue I am having is in the second set of code, the `argReverse` function.  After the file is opened, in this case I use test.txt, which is a simple text file with a couple lines of phrases and empty lines, the first use of `getc` returns a segmentation fault.  I read this is a permission or failed file opening, but I'm not sure what to do to fix this.  I'm trying to open the last file first and work down from there, obviously, and this should be able to handle multiple files, but I can't even open one.  I'm not sure what to do to fix this.  I've tried moving the `getc` outside of the `while` loop, same problem.  I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with opening the file, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: 1) `char currInput; ....    while (currInput != EOF){` uses a variable that had not yet been initialized.  2) `char currInput;` should be `int`.  3) Likely other issues.

Comment: The `currInput` logic is messed.  It appears that it can stay in the `while (currInput != NEWLINE)` loop even once it becomes `EOF`.  Maybe replace with `while (currInput != NEWLINE && currInput != EOF){`

Comment: It runs past that while check though, so that doesn't appear to be a problem, in regards to the `while(currInput != EOF)`.  As for `argv[argc]` always returning null...what should I do to fix that?  Should I just pass another `int` containing the `argc` value?

Comment: I tried the while `(currInput != NEWLINE && currInput != EOF){` but it doesn't seem to fix the output being wrong.

Comment: prototypes needs to be outside of any function, preferably before any function.  Then the compiler can see the prototype when it gets to the actual function declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notes on style:**

The `bool` type, and `true` and `false` are defined in `<stdbool.h>`.

Use character constants like `'A' 'Z' 'a' 'z' '\n'` instead of hard-coded numbers, and/or use the character classification functions like `isalpha` from `<ctype.h>`.

The "reverse" functions just return 0 when they end, so there's no point in returning anything. They should be declared as returning `void`. If they did return something useful, I would return that value from `main` (eliminating the `if` statements). For example,

```
if ( argc == 1 )
    return noArgReverse();
```

Putting large arrays on the stack is generally a bad idea. (Large is subjective, but I use 2K bytes as a rule of thumb.) For a non-reentrant function, you can declare the arrays as `static` to get them off the stack. For a reentrant function, you can `malloc` the arrays, and `free` them at the end.

**Notes on design:**

The `fgets` function will read a line and put it into a buffer. No need to read a character at a time.

When processing command line arguments, the canonical loop is

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
        printf( "argv[%d] is \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i] );
}
```

The reason for your seg-fault is that you are using `argv[argc]`, which the C specification guarantees to be `NULL`. So you are passing `NULL` to `fopen`. Furthermore, you should always check the return value from `fopen`, because `fopen` will return `NULL` if it is unable to open the file.

By far the biggest design issue in the code is repetition. You have two almost-identical functions, which is a nightmare to debug and maintain, since every change needs to be made twice, and tested twice. The solution is to define a `reverse` function that takes a file pointer as input. The `main` function should take care of opening/closing the files, or can pass `stdin` when there aren't any args.

**Sample code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXL 10000
#define MAXW  5000

void reverse( FILE *fp );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc < 2 )
    {
        reverse( stdin );
        return 0;
    }

    FILE *fp;
    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        printf( "----- %s -----\n", argv[i] );
        if ( (fp = fopen( argv[i], "r" )) == NULL )
        {
            printf( "***Error: unable to open file\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            reverse( fp );
            fclose( fp );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void reverse( FILE *fp )
{
    static char line[MAXL];   // buffer for the input line
    static char *word[MAXW];  // array of pointers to the words on the line

    while ( fgets( line, MAXL, fp ) != NULL )
    {
        int i = -1;
        int count = 0;        // count of words on the line
        for (;;)
        {
            // skip any non-alpha characters
            for ( i++; line[i]; i++ )
                if ( isalpha( line[i] ) )
                    break;

            // check if we've reached the end of the line
            if ( !line[i] )
                break;

            // add the pointer to the word list
            word[count++] = &line[i];

            // scan till we reach the end of the word
            for ( i++; line[i]; i++ )
                if ( !isalpha( line[i] ) )
                    break;

            // check if we've reached the end of the line
            if ( !line[i] )
                break;

            // terminate the word
            line[i] = '\0';
        }

        // output the words in reverse order
        for ( i = count - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            printf( "%s ", word[i] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my professor said I HAVE to use `getc`.  He also told me he does not care how much memory or how efficient the code is, though your comments are quite valid.  Also, I have to be able to handle the fact that `stdin` is going to be used if he doesn't pass any files as arguments.  In addition, all things have to printed to `stdout` or `stderr`.

Comment: The first `if` statement in `main` handles the no-arguments case by passing `stdin` to the `reverse` function. Note that `stdin` is a file pointer `FILE *` just like any other. As for using `getc`, the solution in that case is to write your own `fgets` function, that reads a line into a buffer.  One of the problems in your code is that you're mixing the code that reads the line into the code that parses the line. The resulting code has `getc` at three different levels of nested loops, which you will find difficult to unravel.

Comment: Alright, thank you kindly for the help.  I'll get to writing that `fgets` function.

Comment: getc() is a very bad function to use, is being depreciated, etc.  use fgetc() for both files and stdin